# How To Add Entity_ID Column (Entity ID) To Userpoints List Transactions in Admin?

Tags: userpoints

/admin/config/people/userpoints/transaction

This report is generated in the Userpoints module. It does -everything- we need, but it doesn't display the entity_id field (the ID of the source which generated the points transaction.) There's no hook into the code which generates the report.

I can get it to do what I want by hacking the userpoints.module directly and changing two lines (the header array and the row array around line 1925 and 1995).

But is there a way to add this column -without- hacking the module directly? I don't see any hooks into those functions. I'd =much= rather do something that doesn't change the original code if possible.